# Firebase function that disallow for duplicates

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a firebase function (real time database trigger) that will disallow to create / update records if they already exists.

To make it simple. I have a db with seat numbers: `/seats/${number}/some_data`. Now two users at this same moment make a request to create an object `/seats/1`. What will happen is that the first request will create a record and the second will update it.

What I want to do it to check if record already exist, and if yest than do nothing!

I'm fighting with `onCreate` and `onUpdate` triggers but with no luck as for now. Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) would be very useful in this situation. The validate rule or write rule could deny a write if the data trying to be written already exists.

Comment: Try to look at `onWrite` guess

Comment: Why are you trying to use Cloud Functions for this? As Jay says, this is fairly simple with just the realtime database: 1) use a transaction on the client, 2) use a security rule that enforced that data can only be added, not updated. E.g. `".write": "!data.exists()"`

Comment: But if you want help figuring out why your Cloud Functions code doesn't work, update your question to include the [minimum complete code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's not that my code doesn't work. I'm not looking for ready solution but to point me direction I should go. I think Jay's and Frank van Puffelen's comments are the best way to go. I have started to take a look at the rules and I think this is what I was looking for! Thanks!